# trigonometry equation sin2x+sin(180-8x)=√2*cos3x

Tags: trigonometry

the equation is: $\sin2x+\sin(180°-8x)=\sqrt2\cos3x$

I tried to solve this equation. I got 2 right answers, but in the book, there are 3 answers.
my answers: $x=9°+27°k, x=27°+72°k$. book adds this answer $x=30°+60°k$

I don't understand what I did wrong. please help .

```
sin2x+sin(180-8x)=√2*cos3x
sin2x+sin8x=√s*cos3x
2*sin5x*cos(-3x)=√2*cos3x
2*sin5x*cos3x=√2*cos3x
2*sin5x=√2
sin5x=√2/2
sin5x = sin45

5x = 45+360k
x = 9 + 27k

5x = 180-45+360k
5x = 135+360k
x = 27+72k
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over here,

$$2\sin 5x \cos 3x = \sqrt{2}\cos 3x$$

$\cos 3x$ should not have been cancelled away from both ends, as doing so eliminates certain solutions. Instead, you should shift them to the same side and do some factorization:

$$2\sin5x\cos3x - \sqrt{2}\cos3x = 0$$
$$\cos3x (2\sin5x - \sqrt2) = 0.$$

From this you get an additional set of answers from $\cos 3x = 0$, namely $$3x = 90^\circ + 180^\circ k$$
$$x = 30^\circ  + 60^\circ k.$$